# text type independent variable to numeric type spark naive bayes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I have doubt with Naive bayes with  numeric and non numeric features .  like I have 5 independent independent parameter on these i want to classify data .

Male,Suspicion of Alcohol,Weekday,12am-4am,75,30-39
Male,Moving Traffic Violation,Weekday,12am-4am,0,20-24
Male,Suspicion of Alcohol,Weekend,4am-8am,12,40-49
Male,Suspicion of Alcohol,Weekday,12am-4am,0,50-59
Female,Road Traffic Collision,Weekend,12pm-4pm,0,20-24
Male,Road Traffic Collision,Weekday,12pm-4pm,0,25-29
Male,Road Traffic Collision,Weekday,8pm-12pm,0,Other
Male,Other,Weekday,8am-12pm,23,60-69
Male,Moving Traffic Violation,Weekend,12pm-4pm,26,30-39
Female,Road Traffic Collision,Weekend,4am-8am,61,16-19
Male,Moving Traffic Violation,Weekend,4pm-8pm,74,25-29
Male,Road Traffic Collision,Weekday,12am-4am,0,Other
Male,Moving Traffic Violation,Weekday,8pm-12pm,0,16-19
Male,Road Traffic Collision,Weekday,8pm-12pm,0,Other
Male,Moving Traffic Violation,Weekend,4am-8am,0,30-39

You can see some parameters are numeric some are non numeric  . Any know how to convert non numeric data to numeric data .

1. How to convert non numeric to numeric
2. If i use TF then it will be right or not
3. If TF is right then why

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following:

- convert each of the features to a categorical value by applying a `factorizer`. An example:
- Feature1: Male = 0  Female = 1
- Feature2:Alcohol=0  collision=1 Moving-Violation=2
- ..

and so on.

Each different possible value of one "column" should have its own specific numerical representation in your factorized result.  Hopefully things like `4pm-8pm` are non-overlapping: but if they are you can start with ignoring that detail and later do some more intelligent manual featurization if time allows.

Each entry/line in your input consists of around a dozen "features". Then you can create a feature vector out of each line.  The results are now `tf-idf ready` (TM).  You can apply the NB algorithm to your newly minted feature vectors - and find relative similarities.